# Entity Framework change schema name at runtime (model first)

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, schema, entity

I have an ASP.NET web application that uses EF 5 and SQL Server. I'm trying to host many instances of identical database tables in different database schemas. Suppose we have table Tbl, we have customer1.Tbl and customer2.Tbl in the same database. WebApp1 will use customer1.Tbl and WebApp2 will use customer2.Tbl. In EF5 code first there is

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
```

method and schema name can be set when application is started with a code like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tbl>().ToTable("Tbl", schemaName: "customer1");
```

The problem is I'm not using code first. OnModelCreating is never called.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try removing Schema attributes from the SSDL part of the edmx. This way EF should not qualify tables with the schema for queries and the database should use the default schema for the user. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I would also like to see how the schema can be changed, as Pawel's suggestion will not work for my scenario where I would like to open two instances of DbContext but the second with a different schema.